# Wtf IE7 - AJAX calls using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have tested this on Firefox, Opera and Seamonkey. It works fine. When it comes to Internet Explorer 7. It works but upto a certain point. I am making an AJAX call to a PHP script every few seconds. In IE7 it makes the first AJAX call and it retrieves the data but it doesn't do it again ever. Even though i have a setTimeout function in the else block. **WHY?** :(

```
startTime = setTimeout('getStatus()', 5000); 

}//function convertNow
```

function getStatus()
{

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "fileReader.php",
    data: 'textFile=' + fileNameTxt,
    success: function(respomse){
    textFileResponse = respomse.split(" ");
    $("#done").html("Downloading & Converting Video...<b style='font-size:17px;color:green;'>" + textFileResponse[0] + "</b><br /><b>" + properFileName + '</b>');
    }
    });//ajax

    if(textFileResponse[0]=='100.0%'){

    }
    else{       
    continueTime = setTimeout('getStatus();', 3000); 
        alert('call end');
    }
```

}

Apologies if any frustration comes through this question. I've been running around like a headless chicken for the past 3 hours.

Thank you for any help.

### EDIT 2

I have added the full function. The setTimeout seems to be working correctly. It must be the AJAX call, am just checking what is being returned. Even stranger! It keeps returning the same value from the AJAX request and its not getting any newer values!! I think Answer 2 might have something.It may be due with cache but how do you over come that?

Comment: Just curious. Are you trying to make the AJAX call in a synchronous way and checking the response immediately? It seems so looking at your code snippet.

Comment: Yes, I use the response and print it to the browser. Its part of my attempt of a progress bar/report.

Comment: Are you sure the call is getting finished? Could you put some logging/alert just before you do setTimeout?

Comment: I used alerts after each setTimeout and it alerts me correctly whenever it makes an AJAX call or at the very least when it executes the else block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you requesting the ajax call via HTTP GET as opposed to HTTP POST?  IE tends to use cached results of ajax calls unless you use POST instead of GET.

EDIT: Since you've updated your question, I can see that you are indeed using the GET verb.  Change it to POST and I bet your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I am using GET, but after every test and change I make I clear the cache and reload the page, and still gives me the same output!

Comment: @Abs: What Ken meant was that IE caches results between subsequent AJAX calls. Clearing the cache before reloading page doesnt help. You must explicitly set a header telling IE not to cache.

Comment: I am understanding now and he is right i think (see edit 2). How can I do this?

Comment: Or include ‘cachebuster’ random-number-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all sure on this but are you missing the `;`?

from:

```
setTimeout('getStatus()', 3000);
```

to:

```
setTimeout('getStatus();', 3000);
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't help IE7 make the call again!

Comment: Incidentally you can save yourself a pointless string compilation by saying “setTimeout(getStatus, 3000);” directly on the getStatus function object.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use the GET request and simply add

```
cache: false
```

to the $.ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that textFileResponse is set in the function declaration of the success handler for the AJAX call yet referenced as an array immediately after making the AJAX call. Perhaps in IE 7 the success handler hasn't completed before the array reference which would throw a java script error, thus the setTimeout would never run.